# Unable to pass Props to grand child component via Link in React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**Parent Component (UserList Component):**

```
const UsersList = (props) => {    
    const removeCandidateById = (id) => {
        props.removeCandidateDetails(id);
    }    
    const RenderUsersList = props.CandidateDetails.map((userDetails) => {
        return (
            <UserCard userDetails={userDetails} removeUser={removeCandidateById }  key={userDetails.id}/>
        )
})
```

From `UserCard Component` I would like to pass the props data to another child component via the `Link` `state` object like `state: { userDetails: this.props.userDetails }` , but its always undefined in the grand child component which is configured in the `/userDetail` path.

I tried by Functional component way also. Via Link I cant get the solution for this.

**Child Component (UserCard Component) :**

```
class UserCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { id, name, age, occupation, phone, imgUrL } = props.userDetails;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Col className="col col-lg-2 mb-3 mt-4">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title"> {this.name}</h5>
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: `/userDetail/${this.id}`,
                state: { userDetails: this.props.userDetails },
              }}
            >
              <img
                className="img"
                src={avatar}
                style={this.imgStyle}
                alt="avatar"
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}

export default UserCard;
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: If the component that should read history object is a class component, then you should wrap it with withRouter

Comment: @User456 I am using router dom version - 6.3.0

Comment: @Maxime where should I wrap it with <Router>? `usercard's` render content should be wrapped with <Router>? I am getting the error `"You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app"`  - I have my routing set up at App.js with <Router>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your version of react-router-dom is 6.3.0. In the new version, you set the state for Link differently. The state's value in the object passed to the `to` prop will be ignored, so you need to pass the state separately in the `state` prop.

```html
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/userDetail/${this.id}`,
  }}
  state={{ userDetails: this.props.userDetails }}
>
  <img
    className="img"
    src={avatar}
    style={this.imgStyle}
    alt="avatar"
  />
</Link>
```

Now, to access the state, you can extract `state` from the react-router-dom `useLocation` hook.

```js
const { state } = useLocation();
// you have two ways to access userDetails
const { userDetails } = state // 1
const userDetails = state.userDetails // 2
```